# How can I use multiple colors in a Label (Xcode/iPad)

Tags: iphone, ipad

For an application I'm building, I dynamically add text to a label. The first part of the label's text has to be black so I choose that color in Interface Builder. However the second part (the first part is a title second part a description) has to be darkgray.

Oh and note: 2 labels is not an option because of positioning.

Comment: You say 2 labels isn't an option, but it is probably the best way to do it (then position it using ‘-sizeToFit‘ and ‘layoutSubviews‘)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct API to do that, however it's easy to subclass UIView class and use drawRect method to draw the strings by yourself using 
`CGContextSetRGBFillColor` to set the color and `NSString`'s `drawInRect:` method to draw portions of text in specified rectangles

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use a UIWebView to Format and color the text. ;-)